# Question regarding usage of "but"

Tags: conjunctions

I have a question regarding the usage of "but".

Suppose a person plays cricket. He does not play football. Which of the following is correct?

> - He plays cricket but football.
> - He plays cricket but not football.

I think the first one to be true. But it seems weird. Most of the time, I've seen the second statement to be used.

Comment: The second one is correct, but I can't give an explanation as to why, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Comment: "He plays cricket but **not** football.", but "He plays every game but football." In the second case, *but* means *except*.

Comment: So @kris! Is the first one correct? If yes, what does it mean?

Comment: The correct versions are the two sentences I stated in the comment above.

Comment: This question is too basic for this site. Please support our proposed sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Second one is correct .I think problem with first version is, you are trying to use but as  **Except** for that **but** should be followed by the word which is subgroup of the other word.Like **Everyone laughed but Tom**. I will leave rest for the others.